# Property 'password' does not exist on type 'User[]'.ts(2339) when trying to hash password

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I'm currently learning Typescript and i'm making a CRUD but i got stuck in one function that is meant to create a user. The thing is that i wanna save a user with Name, last name, email and password(this one has to be hashed). But when i wrote the line to hash the password it gives the error from the title of the question and i haven't found an answer.

> **Create user function**

```
export const createUser = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> => {

    const { body } = req;

    try {

        const emailExists = await getRepository(User).findOne({
            where: {
                email: body.email
            }
        });

        if (emailExists) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                message: 'User already exists'
            });
        }

        let user = getRepository(User).create(req.body);
        let salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        user.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt); // <----- Property 'password' does not exist on type 'User[]'.ts(2339)
        await getRepository(User).save(user);
        return res.status(200).json(user);

    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            message: 'Error creating user'
        });
    }

}
```

User entity (TypeORM)

```js
@Entity()
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    firstName: string;

    @Column()
    lastName: string;

    @Column()
    email: string;

    @Column()
    password: string;
}
```

Comment: `Property 'password' does not exist on type 'User[]'` Seems to indicate that you are trying to access the `password` property on a an array of users (type: `User[]`). When you hover over `user` in `let user = ...` in your IDE, what type does it say that variable is?

Comment: `getRepository(User).create(req.body)` must return an array of users (`User[]`). If you want to access the property on your `User` class, you'll need to access an item from the array (assuming that is actually what `create` returns).

Comment: @AlexWayne it says "any"